# jboss-as-maven-plugin can't deploy to remote Jboss?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss

I've tried for days to use jboss-as-maven-plugin to deploy web projects to remote Jboss as 7，but it didn't work. The following is my pom.xml

```
    <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>7.3.Final</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                            <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                            <port>9999</port>
                        </configuration>
<executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>deploy</id>
                                    <phase>install</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
```

I have error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.3.
CR1b:deploy (default) on project MessagePushX-RELEASE: Could not execute goal de
ploy on test.war. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could no
t connect to remote://192.168.1.104:9999. The connection timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The reasons could be many. Can you confirm that you have a management port open and accessible at 192.168.1.104:9999?

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly says it can't connect to "remote://192.168.1.104:9999". Verify that it's the correct  configuration and verify your connectivity to that destination.

You can try

```
telnet 192.168.1.104 9999
```

from your machine to see if you've got connection.

Comment: reason for the downvote would be nice. I can't reason myself why this would be a bad answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the solution you want, but it's one we use.

You can map a network drive to the deploy folder you want your files in, then have maven build it's output to that folder.

For example, on our local machines, maven builds the jar directly in the deploy folder in JBoss.

Another option is to configure JBoss to use an alternate deploy folder in addition to the default. Then have maven build to this alternate folder where JBoss will pick your files up from.

Just a couple of different options to think about if this other one still isn't working for you.

Comment: can you give reasons as to why this solution would be better than doing it with maven-as plugin?

Comment: No not really. I probably wouldn't suggest it as a good solution, just an option if you cannot get the other to work and are against a hard deadline. I know sometimes all I'm looking for is a way to make things happen. I've never used the plugin to remotely deploy like that, and I think I am going to research that option more now that I know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

### Changes to standalone.xml

Location: (/usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml)

- modified standalone to have auto-deploy zipped true (so as no need to create war.dodeploy file) and auto-deploy-exploded false

  ```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
      <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/>
  ```
- added jsp-configuration

  ```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
          <configuration>
              <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
          </configuration>
  ```
- added jboss-as-configuration in maven pom.xml

  ```
   <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>7.3.Final</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <hostname>192.168.0.105</hostname>
                      <port>9999</port>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <phase>install</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>deploy</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>

              </plugin>
  ```
- you should have your jboss instance started from eclipse or outside and bind to same IP instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1.
  You can do this either from your command line or from eclipse by changing host to your IP address: 192.168.0.105
- After this you can use the following maven goal to redeploy changes after each change. Also please note you might have to use deploy initially and then redeploy.

  ```
  -e -X jboss-as:redeploy
  ```